Why is Joshua crowned in Zechariah 6?
I've understood that many interpret this section as a prefiguration of the Messiah (Jesus) but, even if this is the case, why was Joshua crowned with a king's crown? He wasn't a king and surely there are clearer ways of prophesying Jesus here?

Zech 6:12, 13 - And you are to tell him that this is what the LORD of
Hosts says: ‘Here is a man whose name is the Branch, and He will
branch out from His place and build the temple of the LORD. Yes, He
will build the temple of the LORD; He will be clothed in splendor and
will sit on His throne and rule. And He will be a priest on His
throne, and there will be peaceful counsel between the two.’



11 You will take silver and gold, and make crowns; place one on
the head of Joshua, son of Jehozadak, the high priest. 12 And say to
him: Thus says the Lord of hosts: There is a man whose name is
Branch—and from his place he will branch out and he will build the
temple of the Lord. 13 He will build the temple of the Lord, and
taking up the royal insignia, he will sit as ruler upon his throne.
The priest will be at his right hand, and between the two of them
there will be peaceful understanding. 14 The other crown will be in
the temple of the Lord as a gracious reminder to Heldai, Tobijah,
Jedaiah, and the son of Zephaniah.


First, we should be aware that the high priest's head was traditionally adorned by what is called a gold "crown" in may translations, (Exodus 29:6, Leviticus 8:9, etc.) also referred to as a diadem or a turban with an ornate gold band, with "scared to the Lord" inscribed on it.
Second, even if Joshua's crown was special, it was not a royal crown. The text is explicit in saying that it was not the high priest but the future king that would take up the "royal insignia" while the "other crown" would remain in the temple, apparently as a memorial to those who had donated  their wealth for the project.

Yes, a close look at the text shows that v12 is addressing Joshua, not describing him (which is where the occasional confusion comes from). The Branch is the Davidic prince.

@StephenDisraeli, as I read it vs 12 addresses the prophet Zechariah, who is instructed to speak in God's name to Joshua.

Sorry, it would have been more accurate to say that the message in v12 is "to be addressed" to Joshua. I was rebutting the assumption (implied in the question) that it is addressed to somebody else and calling Joahua the Branch.

Zechariah 6:11-13 (KJV)

11 Then take silver and gold, and make crowns, and set them upon the head of Joshua the son of Josedech, the high priest;
12 And speak unto him, saying, Thus speaketh the Lord of hosts, saying, Behold the man whose name is The Branch; and he shall grow up out of his place, and he shall build the temple of the Lord:
13 Even he shall build the temple of the Lord; and he shall bear the glory, and shall sit and rule upon his throne; and he shall be a priest upon his throne: and the counsel of peace shall be between them both.

Let's keep the following points in mind:

The word "crowns" in Zechariah 6:11 is plural.
The Branch has the roles of king and priest upon his throne (Zechariah 6:13)
Joshua and Jesus share the same linguistic roots and meaning - "Yahweh is salvation" or "The Lord saves" - with Joshua being the Old Testament form of the name and Jesus being the New Testament form.

The Bridgeway Bible Commentary provides this explanation

Just as the setting up of the Messiah’s kingdom will be marked by the crowning of the Messiah as universal king, so the re-establishment of the nation Israel was marked by the crowning of Joshua. The crown was made from gold and silver brought from Babylon by some exiles who had recently arrived in Jerusalem (9-11). A coronation of the high priest was unusual, but because the restored nation of Israel was still under Persian rule, a coronation of the Davidic prince Zerubbabel may have appeared to be an act of rebellion. But the Persians were not likely to object to a religious ceremony marking the restoration of Israel’s national life and the reconstruction of their temple.
Zechariah’s words, spoken on behalf of God, further indicate that the crown rightly belonged to Zerubbabel; for though the words were addressed to Joshua they applied to Zerubbabel. It was Zerubbabel, not Joshua, who was the ‘branch’ in David’s family tree, the royal descendant entitled to the throne of Israel. Joshua’s rightful place was as the high priest who assisted the civil ruler. The two men, because of the peaceful understanding between them, led the nation in the ways of God. Their joint rule fittingly foreshadowed the rule of the true ‘Branch’, the king-priest Messiah (12-13; cf. 3:8; see also notes on Haggai 2:20-23).

Conclusion
Under the Persian regime, Zerubbabel, though the rightful heir, was political unfit for coronation. However, the religious leader Joshua was not. In this context, Joshua symbolizes the future Messiah who will hold the titles of both king and priest, a concept illustrated in depth in the Book of Hebrews.

14 Therefore, since we have a great high priest who has ascended into heaven, Jesus the Son of God, let us hold firmly to the faith we profess. (Hebrews 4:14 NIV)


5 In the same way, Christ did not take on himself the glory of becoming a high priest. But God said to him, “You are my Son; today I have become your Father.” 6 And he says in another place, “You are a priest forever, in the order of Melchizedek.” (Hebrews 5:5-6 NIV)


This Melchizedek was king of Salem and priest of God Most High. (Hebrews 7:1 NIV)


All that one can say about the overall prophecy in Zech 6:9-15 is that it has not been fulfilled yet.  It appears to either still to be fulfilled or a failed prophecy because of the primary condition that we read at it end:

Zech 6:14, 15 - The crown will reside in the temple of the LORD as a
memorial to Helem,e Tobijah, Jedaiah, and the graciousf son of
Zephaniah. 15Even those far away will come and build the temple of the
LORD, and you will know that the LORD of Hosts has sent Me to you.
This will happen if you diligently obey the voice of the LORD your God.”

Now, it is obvious that some of the Jews, after the Babylonian captivity, returned and over the next 400 years became very legalistic and ultimately rejected Jesus as Messiah by saying:

John 19:15 - At this, they shouted, “Away with Him! Away with Him!
Crucify Him!” “Shall I crucify your King?” Pilate asked. “We have no
king but Caesar,” replied the chief priests.

Thus, not only did the Jewish authorities reject their only valid Messiah, they also rejected Jesus as their rightful king.  This lead, about 40 years later to the destruction of the Temple and the Jewish nation by the Romans.
Thus, I see no reason to believe that Zech 6 has yet been fulfilled.  No one remotely resembling "the Branch" has arisen as priest and King who rebuilt the temple.
ANNEX - "Branch"
In other places, "The Branch" is a title of Messiah as per:

Isa 11:1 - Then a shoot will spring up from the stump of Jesse, and a Branch from his roots will bear fruit.
Isa 4:2 - On that day the Branch of the LORD will be beautiful and glorious, and the fruit of the land will be the pride and glory of Israel’s survivors.
Jer 23:5 - Behold, the days are coming, declares the LORD, when I will raise up for David a righteous Branch, and He will reign wisely as King and will administer justice and righteousness in the land.
Jer 33:15 - In those days and at that time I will cause to sprout for David a righteous Branch, and He will administer justice and righteousness in the land.
Zech 3:8 - Hear now, O high priest Joshua, you and your companions seated before you, who are indeed a sign. For behold, I am going to bring My servant, the Branch.

